# How to add arrow labels to points in python geodataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, matplotlib, geopandas

My code currently outputs a visualization that looks something like this:

[image]

And I would like to be able to add a feature which has arrows pointing to each location dot, in which each arrow has a label name. Basically, I want to get output that looks like this:

[image]

I would want the program to automatically choose an arrow spacing so that the label names (like "A", "B:, etc) do not collide/ with each other. Is this possible to do automatically?

Here is my code so far which displays the first image:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Point
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
import json 


#This function creates the pandas dataframe where each row is the (latitude, longitude) of a location. The first column is latitude, and the second column is longitude
def createLatitudeLongitudeDataFrame(inputJsonFolder, inputJsonFilename):
    data = json.load(open(inputJsonFolder + "\\" + inputJsonFilename))
    latitudes = []
    longitudes = []
    for location in data["locations"]:
        latitudes.append(location["coordinates"]["latitude"])
        longitudes.append(location["coordinates"]["longitude"])
    
    data_tuples = list(zip(latitudes, longitudes))
    df = pd.DataFrame(data_tuples, columns=["Latitudes", "Longitudes"])

    return df


#This function creates the map of the locations based on the dataframe.
def createMapOfLocations(df):
    geometry = [Point(yx) for yx in zip(df['Longitudes'], df['Latitudes'])]   
    gdf = GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geometry)   

    #This is a simple map that goes with geopandas
    world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
    gdf.plot(ax=world.plot(figsize=(10, 6)), marker='o', color='red', markersize=15)

    plt.show()
        


def main():
    inputJsonFolder = "\\inputFolder"

    
    inputJsonFilename = "testing.json"

    df = createLatitudeLongitudeDataFrame(inputJsonFolder, inputJsonFilename)
    createMapOfLocations(df) 


main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data and code below can not answer all of your requirements. It shows you what the data you need and the code that plots annotation texts on the map. When there are many texts on the map, it is difficult to place them properly without clashing. A program that can arrange them to get the perfect results in all situations is long and complicate.

The input data:

```
Content of "testing.json"
The `locations` data should contain:
- (long, lat) of the location
- name, i.e. "City_A"
- (shift_long, shift_lat) for positioning of the `name` away from the location to avoid clashing

{"locations": [
    {"coordinates": {"latitude": 12, "longitude": 99, "name": "City_A", "shift": [-19,-16]}},
    {"coordinates": {"latitude": 55, "longitude": 68, "name": "City_B", "shift": [15,15]}},
    {"coordinates": {"latitude": 36, "longitude": 35, "name": "City_C", "shift": [-17,18]}} ]}
```

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Point
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
import json 


def createLatitudeLongitudeDataFrame(inputJsonFolder, inputJsonFilename):
    data = json.load(open(inputJsonFolder + "/" + inputJsonFilename))
    latitudes = []
    longitudes = []
    names = []   # annotation name
    shifts = []  # annotation shift(dlong, dlat)
    for location in data["locations"]:
        latitudes.append(location["coordinates"]["latitude"])
        longitudes.append(location["coordinates"]["longitude"])
        names.append(location["coordinates"]["name"])
        shifts.append(location["coordinates"]["shift"])

    data_tuples = list(zip(latitudes, longitudes, names, shifts))
    df = pd.DataFrame(data_tuples, columns=["Latitudes", "Longitudes", "Names", "Shifts"])
    return df

#This function creates the map of the locations based on the dataframe.
def createMapOfLocations(df):
    geometry = [Point(yx) for yx in zip(df['Longitudes'], df['Latitudes'])]   
    gdf1 = GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geometry)   

    #This is a simple map that goes with geopandas
    world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

    # Need ax1 for reuse
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))
    world.plot(ax=ax1, alpha=0.5)
    gdf1.plot(ax=ax1, marker='o', color='red', markersize=15)

    # ---------------
    # Plot annotation
    # Note the values of xytext, it needs good offset to avoid clashes
    # ---------------
    gdf1.apply(lambda ro: 
               ax1.annotate(
                text=ro['Names'], 
                xy=ro.geometry.centroid.coords[0], 
                xytext=[ro.geometry.centroid.coords[0][0]+ro['Shifts'][0], 
                        ro.geometry.centroid.coords[0][1]+ro['Shifts'][1]], 
                xycoords='data',
                size="small", color="k",
                ha="center", va="center",
                arrowprops=dict(
                            arrowstyle='->', 
                            connectionstyle="arc3,rad=-0.05",
                            color="k"
                        )
                ), axis=1)

    # Set extent of the required map
    ax1.set_xlim(-25,120)
    ax1.set_ylim(-15,75)

    plt.show()



def main():
    inputJsonFolder = "./inputFolder"
    inputJsonFilename = "testing.json"
    df = createLatitudeLongitudeDataFrame(inputJsonFolder, inputJsonFilename)
    createMapOfLocations(df)
    print(df)

main()
```

[image: theplot]